# Trying to install Dradis on Mac OS X Catalina gives me an error, “You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.”

Tags: ruby, macos-catalina, gem

I'm trying install [Dradis](https://dradis.com/ce/documentation/install_git.html) in my Mac OS X Catalina

[image]

```
git clone https://github.com/dradis/dradis-ce.git
cd dradis-ce/
./bin/setup
```

I kept getting

> You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.

---

## and

Yes, I have Ruby installed

```
⚡️  dradis-ce  which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
⚡️  dradis-ce  ruby --version
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin19]
⚡️  dradis-ce
```

Comment: "You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory." So give yourself write permission?

Comment: I'm on a Mac, and logged in as admin as user : kyo

Comment: That doesn't mean you have permission. What are the **current** permissions on that folder?

Comment: See if adding `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` to the end of your `~/.bash_profile` helps; source for this tip can be [found here](https://medium.com/fusionqa/no-write-permissions-for-the-library-ruby-gems-2-0-0-directory-after-installing-rbenv-bfc3fa47a467). Do that and close the terminal and open it up again and see if that clears things up. @DavidPostill Generally one doesn’t face such permission change issues for stuff like this. The issue is most likely the `dradis-ce` Ruby lib directory is not being checked *before* the system one is checked in `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0`.

Comment: @JakeGould, now I can't run `bundle install`, I kept getting `Your Ruby version is 2.6.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.4.1`

Comment: @kyo Well, then undo that change!

Answer (score 0):

I ran this

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0
```

I can by pass that error now.

```
⚡️  dradis-ce  ./bin/setup 

== Enabling default add-ons ==
== Installing dependencies ==
Fetching bundler-2.1.4.gem
Successfully installed bundler-2.1.4
Parsing documentation for bundler-2.1.4
Installing ri documentation for bundler-2.1.4
Done installing documentation for bundler after 2 seconds
1 gem installed
Your Ruby version is 2.6.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.4.1
Your Ruby version is 2.6.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.4.1

== Command ["bundle install"] failed ==
⚡️  dradis-ce
```

Comment: `chmod 777` is never a good idea even if it seems to “solve” things. If you run Ruby you don’t muck with system gems. [Read up on the issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54873916); you most likely could solve the issue with a user-specific Ruby environment being setup for Dradis.

Comment: I’ll update to 644 then.

Comment: `644` is appropriate for files. For directories it should be `755`. Directories will becoming inaccessible without the execution bit set which is the main difference between `644` and `755`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this issue could be fixed by installing your dependencies elsewhere.

```
$ cat ~/.bundle/config
---
BUNDLE_PATH: "vendor/bundle"
```

That way all my gems are installed in the same folder as the app.

```
$ cd dradis-ce/
$ ./bin/setup
```

Should result in bundler installing all gem dependencies in `dradis-ce/vendor/bundle/`